# Angular ng build -prod error: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I run `ng build --target=production` I get the following error:

> ERROR in
>   C:/Repo/NewCo/src/$$_gendir/app/fu/bar/fubar.component.ngfactory.ts
>   (4011,35): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call
>   target.

I don't even know where to start with this...It would be useful if `ng build` gave me a little more insight into:

- Which supplied parameters
- Which call target
- Which line number
- Exactly where this error is occurring

Can anyone explain how I can identify any of the above?

Comment: post your fubar.component.ts !! the error must be coming while ng serve too

Comment: @ParthGhiya no all works fine for `ng serve`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably calling a method from your template which shouldn't (or should) have parameters.

Something like this:

`*ngIf="shouldShow()"`

`shouldShow(show: boolean){//do some}`

As you can see these the supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Comment: The simplest answers are always the best...and this was exactly right! Thank you!